# Binding Gridview from multiple Datasource

Tags: c#

I'm trying to bind multiple datasource to one gridview. it is possible to do this?

Comment: both the table has same structure?

Comment: check this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/82c164a5-4175-4b18-a326-e0509ae79b85/

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. You might to want to merge the result of both datasource and bind the merged result to the gridview.